# Installing cURL from Macports fails

Tags: macports

I'm trying to install `libusb-devel` using Macports on a friend's Mac (we need it in order to install Osceleton). On my computer, the installation went perfectly well, but I'm stuck while installing it on his.

One of the dependencies of `libusb-devel` is `curl`. However, installing `curl` seems to fail. During the configuration of `curl`, an error message is shown and the installation quits. I'm referred to the log, where this is the relevant part for the error:

```
:info:configure configure: found both libz and libz.h header
:info:configure checking for "/dev/urandom"... configure: error: cannot check for file existence when cross compiling
:info:configure shell command " cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_net_curl/work/curl-7.21.4-ppc" && ./configure --prefix=/opt/local --disable-dependency-tracking --disable-dependency-tracking --enable-ipv6 --without-gnutls --without-gssapi --without-librtmp --without-libssh2 --without-nss --without-polarssl --without-spnego --with-ssl --disable-ares --disable-ldap --disable-ldaps --with-libidn --with-zlib=/opt/local --disable-dependency-tracking --with-ca-bundle=/opt/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt --host=powerpc-apple-darwin10.7.0 " returned error 1
:error:configure Target org.macports.configure returned: configure failure: shell command failed (see log for details)
:debug:configure Backtrace: configure failure: shell command failed (see log for details)
    while executing
"$procedure $targetname"
:info:configure Warning: the following items did not execute (for curl): org.macports.destroot org.macports.configure org.macports.build
:notice:configure Log for curl is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_net_curl/main.log
```

If I run the configure-script myself, using the command given in the log, all goes well and `curl` is perfectly installed. However, Macports is not happy with this, because I get errors telling me that certain files already exist etc. Also, installing `curl` directly using Macports seems to give trouble.

Because of this, I can't continue the installation of `libusb-devel`, and we need it quite soon for a school project. Can anyone help?

TIA

EDIT: the entire logfile can be found here: http://pastebin.com/2XAMHv5M . He's running Mac OS X 10.6.6.

Comment: Im no expert about MacPorts, and very likeley it doesent solve your question, but have you ever tried `homebrew`? Its another mananger, but to my opinion its faster, easier and fails much less. Check if `curl` is available for `homebrew`, and if it is, I recomend it much more than MacPorts.

Comment: Macs come with curl. Type `man curl` in Terminal.

Comment: @Nathan Be that as it may, MacPorts/libusb-devel wants to install its own curl.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are trying to compile for the ppc architecture thus the error in cross-compiling.

Did you upgrade to Snow Leopard leaving macports on - the only wa[y to upgrade macports across operating systems is to reinstall.](http://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration)

Otherwise did you choose the correct [dmg](http://www.macports.org/install.php) to install from - it is OS dependant.

Otherwise you need to look at /opt/local/etc/macports/macports.conf and see what [build_arch](http://guide.macports.org/) is set to. The default (or not set) on a new Snow Leopard macports install is 32 or 64 bit Intel code depending on the CPU you have.